# Protect angular application with password

Tags: angular, angular10

I would like to protect my application with a password. When a user opens the app he has to type in the correct password then he is redirected to the main page of the application.

I tried creating a component with simple password input that if validated successfully would redirect using routing, but that doesn't work since the user can still just type in the correct url (`/invitation`) and bypass the password validation.

```
  validatePassword(input: string): void {
    if (this.password === input) {
      this.router.navigate(['/invitation']);
    }
  }
```

What is the correct way to go around this problem?

Comment: Use route guards for allow/deny access to the given route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, you can't.

Anything security related on a frontend is not secure. You can use a [guard](https://angular.io/guide/router#preventing-unauthorized-access) to hide the page, but with a little knowledge, this can be bypassed. You should instead protect your data (API). How to depends on your stack.

Answer (score 0):

[Angular - Preventing unauthorized access](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/3a48c0739d8142affe0ddef2ed9b0fe84a914a33/aio/content/guide/router.md#preventing-unauthorized-access)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28932794)

Comment: Noted. For now, I've changed the URL to a specific GitHub commit, which is less likely to change.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the easy way just to be to add a password page and save something in html storage, then check on every page load? I suppose the APIs can still be called, but it would prevent from viewing